# Excel VBA Change Visible Slicer Items

Tags: excel, vba, slicers

I am trying to set up a worksheet where the user will enter a date into a specified cell (in this case $D$5). Based on the entry in that cell I want to remove buttons/filter options in my slicer.

To give more context, I have a dataset of open orders and a pivot table showing the details of those orders. I created a slicer linked to the pivot table to filter by order number. Once the user selects a date (in $D$5) I want the slicer to show only orders that are meant to ship on that date. From there the user can then filter the pivot table with the order number slicer that has only the relevant orders shipping on the selected day.

I have only been able to find code to select or deselect the filters but not remove them.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I have tired using the

`SlicerCache.Selected = TRUE or FALSE`

But that just selects or deselects the filters, but does not remove the buttons.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub FilterSlicer()

'Declare Variables
Dim xlApp As Application
Dim xlActiveBook As Workbook
Dim xlActiveSheet As Worksheet

Dim OpenOrderTable As ListObject

Dim sl As Slicer
Dim sc As SlicerCache
Dim si As SlicerItem

'Grab Application
Set xlApp = Application
'Grab Active book
Set xlActiveBook = xlApp.ThisWorkbook


'Grab OpenOrder Slicer Caches
Set sc = xlActiveBook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Order_Number")


'Update Slicer Caches values based on the date picked on the sheet.

'First - stop pivot table from refreshing after each pivot item is changed
For Each pt In sc.PivotTables
    pt.ManualUpdate = True
Next pt

Debug.Print sc.SlicerItems(1).Name


'Second - update slicer item visibility

'One slicer must always remain visible so make first item visible then check if it should be at the end
sc.SlicerItems(1).Selected = True


'Unselected all other slicer items
For i = 2 To sc.SlicerItems.Count
    If sc.SlicerItems(i).Selected Then sc.SlicerItems(i).Selected = False
Next i

'Remove specific slicer buttons based on user entry
'***THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO ADD CODE TO REMOVE SLICER BUTTONS***




'Allow pivot table to update
For Each pt In sc.PivotTables
    pt.ManualUpdate = False
Next
    


End Sub
```

EDIT:

After some further research I think it has something to do with the SlicerCache.VisibleSlicerItems property but I don't know how to properly use or reference it

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Sub FilterPT()
    Dim vDate, sItem As SlicerItem
    vDate = [A15]
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_SalesDate")
        For Each sItem In .SlicerItems
            sItem.Selected = (vDate = CDate(sItem.Value))
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]